# Dired. First show list of folders

Tags: dired

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+

Here example of my folder's content:

[image: dired]

As you can see the files and folder are mixed. But I want first to show list of folders and after show list of files.
Is it possible?

---

With respect to the answer by @Drew:

I install `dired-sort-menu` and add in my init.el the next line:

```
(add-hook 'dired-load-hook
          (lambda () (require 'dired-sort-menu)))
```

and restart Emacs. But ... how open sort menu? When I mouse right click on Dired buffer I get another menu.

Here my screenshot:

[image: dired_right_mouse_click]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### External ls

GNU's `ls` has an option `--group-directories-first`, and you can control the list of options passed to `ls` by dired with the variable `dired-listing-switches` (assuming that you haven't already customized this, you'd set it to `-al --group-directories-first`).

Unfortunately, on Windows, emacs usually uses lisp emulation of `ls` and as you can see from the docstring of `ls-lisp--insert-directory`, not all switches are supported — in particular, `--group-directories-first` is not.

However, if you use cygwin (or possibly WSL (?)) and have `ls` installed, then you can tell emacs to use the external `ls` program instead of lisp emulation:

```
(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program t)      ;; use external ls
(setq insert-directory-program "c:/cygwin/bin/ls") ;; ls program name
```

(See [the info manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/Dired-ls.html).)

### Emulated lisp ls

Based on [Drew's great answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36317/dired-first-show-list-of-folders/36321#36321), looking at the source of `dired-sort-menu.el`, it appears that there's a (built-in) setting to sort directories before other files in the emulated lisp ls:

```
(setq ls-lisp-dirs-first t)
```

(This will only have an effect if you have `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program` set to `nil`.)

I'm listing this in addition to Drew's answer, in case you might not want to download/use `dired-sort-menu.el`, since it's not actually necessary — it just provides a very nice, convenient interface.

Comment: Googling also reveals some other (hack-ish) suggestions on the [emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortDirectoriesFirst).

Comment: Yes! (setq ls-lisp-dirs-first t)  - this help. So I not need do download dired-sort-menu.el. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Dired Sort Menu](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu) to sort Dired in various ways, including putting the directories first.

[image]

---

The answer to the question you asked after you loaded Dired Sort Menu and Dired+ is this: Use menu-bar menu **Dir** > **Sort By**.

If you have not turned on `menu-bar-mode` then you need to do that to see menu-bar menus (such as **Dir**).

(The screenshot you show for `mouse-3` has the title **This File**. All of its actions apply to the file of the current line. If you select a region with the mouse then you get a different `mouse-3` popup menu, with actions that act on all files in the region. Neither of these menus applies to all of Dired. Use the menu-bar menus for that.)